# Add 1 day to timezone aware timestamp with regards to daylight savings

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals, oracle19c, sql-timestamp

I am trying to add 1 day to a timezone aware timestamp.
In this example I expected `+ interval '1' day` to add 23 hours because DST starts on `2021-03-28 02:00:00` in `Europe/Berlin`, but it behaves the same as `+ interval '24' hour`:

```sql
select timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as before_dst,
       timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' + interval '1' day as plus_1_day,
       timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' + interval '24' hour as plus_24_hour
from dual;
```

| BEFORE_DST | PLUS_1_DAY | PLUS_24_HOUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-28 00:00:00.000000000 +01:00 | 2021-03-29 **01**:00:00.000000000 +02:00 | 2021-03-29 01:00:00.000000000 +02:00 |

Is there a way to add a day to a timestamp so that the beginnings or ends of daylight saving times are respected? For the example above that means a way to have oracle automatically recognize that the day `2021-03-28` only has 23 hours in `Europe/Berlin`.

I attempted to solve this by converting the timestamp to a local timestamp using `at local` before adding a day, but that does not work because `at local` converts the timestamp to the local time zone and not to something like a `LocalDateTime` in java, resulting in the exact same outcome: `+ interval '1' day` always adding exactly 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the timestamp with time zone value to a plain timestamp, which discards the time zone information; then add the 1-day interval, and declare the result to be in the required time zone:

```
from_tz(cast(timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as timestamp) + interval '1' day, 'Europe/Berlin') as plus_1_day
```

or cast to a date (which could be implicit), add a day, and cast back:

```
from_tz(cast(cast(timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as date) + 1 as timestamp), 'Europe/Berlin')
```

Adapting your example and showing the intermediate values:

```
select timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as before_dst,
       cast(timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as timestamp) as as_ts,
       cast(timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as timestamp) + 1 as plus_1_day_ts,
       from_tz(cast(timestamp '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' as timestamp) + interval '1' day, 'Europe/Berlin') as plus_1_day
from dual;
```

| BEFORE_DST | AS_TS | PLUS_1_DAY_TS | PLUS_1_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-28 00:00:00 +01:00 | 2021-03-28 00:00:00 | 2021-03-29 00:00:00 | 2021-03-29 00:00:00 +02:00 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0cbd9fc033c4d48dadf49107fe28ccd8)

This assumes that you're always dealing with a fixed known time zone region; if you actually have a variable or column value with an unknown time zone then you can extract the region from that and use that as the `from_tz()` argument.

You should also be aware that this will work for your example at midnight, but won't work for all times. For example if your starting value was `timestamp '2021-03-27 02:30:00 Europe/Berlin'` then it would fail with "ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval", because it would end up try to declare `2021-03-28 02:30:00` to be in zone Europe/Berlin - and there is no such time, as that falls into the 'lost' hour of 02:00-03:00. Simply adding a day interval handles that - but then doesn't work as you expect in your example...

And this is because of this line [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705):

> Oracle performs all timestamp arithmetic in UTC time.

2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin is 2021-03-27 23:00:00 UTC; adding a day to that is 2021-03-28 23:00:00 UTC; which is 2021-03-29 02:00:00 Europe/Berlin

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the time zone then you can extract the time zone information dynamically from the timestamp:

```sql
SELECT ts,
       FROM_TZ(
         CAST(ts AS TIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         TO_CHAR(ts, 'TZR')
       ) AS ts_plus_one
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ts) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-03-28 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| TS | TS_PLUS_ONE |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-28 00:00:00.000000000 +01:00 | 2021-03-29 00:00:00.000000000 +02:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VzTQf7WJ)