# Add a number of days to a time stamp with time zone while keeping the hour

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Is it possible in Oracle to add a defined number of days to a time stamp with time zone without changing the time when switching from standard time to daylight saving time?

The following `SELECT` Statement show the issue:

```sql
WITH
   days
   AS
      (    SELECT LEVEL AS n
             FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7)
SELECT days.n,
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2024-03-27 03:00:00 Europe/Berlin', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n, 'DAY') AS ts
  FROM days;
```

It returns

| N | TS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-28 03:00:00,000000000 +01:00 |
| 2 | 2024-03-29 03:00:00,000000000 +01:00 |
| 3 | 2024-03-30 03:00:00,000000000 +01:00 |
| 4 | 2024-03-31 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00 |
| 5 | 2024-04-01 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00 |
| 6 | 2024-04-02 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00 |
| 7 | 2024-04-03 04:00:00,000000000 +02:00 |

Starting with N = 4 the hour changes from 3 to 4.

Doing the same in Postgres with

```sql
WITH
   days
   AS
      (SELECT generate_series(1, 7) as n)
SELECT days.n,
         timestamp with time zone '2024-03-27 03:00:00 Europe/Berlin'
       + interval '1 day' * n AS ts
  FROM days;
```

returns

| N | TS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-28 03:00:00.000000 +01:00 |
| 2 | 2024-03-29 03:00:00.000000 +01:00 |
| 3 | 2024-03-30 03:00:00.000000 +01:00 |
| 4 | 2024-03-31 03:00:00.000000 +02:00 |
| 5 | 2024-04-01 03:00:00.000000 +02:00 |
| 6 | 2024-04-02 03:00:00.000000 +02:00 |
| 7 | 2024-04-03 03:00:00.000000 +02:00 |

This is what I would expect to get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130963/add-1-day-to-timezone-aware-timestamp-with-regards-to-daylight-savings

Comment: You can get Oracle's output using PostgreSQL if you use `interval '24 hour'` rather than `interval '1 day'` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OpgOF69X)

Comment: @MT0: Thanks, but I'm looking for oracle to do the same as postgres. ;-)

Comment: @D.Mika Then use the answers in the linked duplicate.